# How to use JQ command to generate random string of length 5, consisting of lowercase letters(a to z)

Tags: random, jq

I am not getting any function to generate random string using JQ filter

I tried to use random and rand function to generate random strings, but JQ is giving error saying random or rand is not defined. I am using 1.7 version of JQ but these functions are not supported in this version.

Comment: What made you think that there is or should be such a function? It has never been. See the [manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/).

Comment: Do you _have_ to use the `jq` command? Why can't you use some other command that _can_ generate random strings?

Answer (score 4):

JQ doesn't have built-ins for generating random data but it's easy to roll your own. For example, if you had an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "foo": 42
  },
  {
    "foo": 5
  }
]
```

and wanted to add a pseudo-random five-character-long `id` field to each object, you could do:

```
def random_words: 
  def lcg($seed):
    (105*$seed + 1)%pow(26; 5) | ., lcg(.);
  lcg(now) | [97 + (./pow(26; range(5)))%26] | implode;

[., [limit(length; random_words)]]
| transpose
| map({id: .[1]}+.[0])
```

And the result would look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "flxai",
    "foo": 42
  },
  {
    "id": "gfqql",
    "foo": 5
  }
]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vP3OPIuhI5o)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you want a high-entropy source of randomness and can use /dev/random
in a bash or bash-like environment,
then the following illustrates a general technique for doing so while
solving the instance of the problem presented by @oguz_ismail on this page.
We suppose the JSON file containing an array of objects is in input.json

```
< /dev/random tr -cd '0-9' | fold -w 1 |
  jq -Mcnr --slurpfile input.json '

# Output: a PRN in range(0;$n) where $n is .
def prn:
  if . == 1 then 0
  else . as $n
  | (($n-1)|tostring|length) as $w
  | [limit($w; inputs)] | join("") | tonumber
  | if . < $n then . else ($n | prn) end
  end;

# pseudo-random lower-case word of the given width
def random_word($width):
  [limit($width; repeat(26|prn)) + 97] | implode;

# Add key id 
reduce $input[][] as $in ([]; . +  [$in | .id = random_word(5)] )
'
```

Of course, for the specific problem at hand, one
could simplify this to:

```
< /dev/random tr -cd 'A-Za-z' | tr A-Z a-z | fold -w 5 |
  jq -cnRr --slurpfile input input.json '
# Add key id 
reduce $input[][] as $in ([]; . +  [$in | .id = input] )
'
```

Illustrative output:

```
[{"foo":42,"id":"rduaf"},{"foo":5,"id":"qcxmw"}]
```